# Get difference of columns with same id

Tags: python, pandas

I've got a dataset like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d = {'id': [1, 2, 2, 2], 
     'date': [np.datetime64('2019-07-01'), np.datetime64('2019-07-02'), 
              np.datetime64('2019-07-06'), np.datetime64('2019-07-19')]} 
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

And I would like to create an extra column, with the difference of adjacent entries with the same id (the data are sorted by id and date). Meaning I would like to get a result like this:

```
    id  date        diff
0   1   2019-07-01  NaN
1   2   2019-07-02  4.0
2   2   2019-07-06  13.0
3   2   2019-07-19  NaN
```

Is there some pandas function that would allow me to do this, instead of using a `for` that would iterate over the whole dataset?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrameGroupBy.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html), subtract `date` and then convert timedeltas to days by [`Series.dt.days`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.days.html):

```
df['diff'] = df.groupby('id')['date'].shift(-1).sub(df['date']).dt.days
print (df)
   id       date  diff
0   1 2019-07-01   NaN
1   2 2019-07-02   4.0
2   2 2019-07-06  13.0
3   2 2019-07-19   NaN
```

Comment: I'm getting this error  'dict' object has no attribute 'groupby'

Comment: @mohan111 - Maybe use `d` instead `df`